# What is the name of Jenkins plugin for GitHub plugin configuration?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github

We need below plugin in Jenkins:

### [image]

Currently I have installed below list of plugins:

```
git:latest
git-client:latest
git-server:latest
github:latest
github-api:latest
github-branch-source:latest
```

---

Am using Jenkins 2.190.2

I could not find GitHub plugin configuration in Jenkins after navigating `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure System`

---

What is the name of the GitHub plugin that needs to be added in plugin list to install using `/usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin that you are looking for is: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-plugin.

You need to go in `Manage Jenkins` > `Global Configuration` to find the GitHub plugin configuration (according the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin)).